# Best practice to create a CI pipeline for AWS Cognito + API Gateway + Lambdas + DynamoDB + SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

Starting with AWS and want to do it right from te beginning. What would be the current state of the art approach to have a complete CI pipeline?

Our idea is to have everything in a local git repository at the company and then we can trigger deployments into the different AWS stages. And with everything we mean everything, so we can automate everything and live completely without the aws web interface.

I went through some tutorials and they all seem to do it differently, tools lile Apex, Amplify, CloudFormation, SAM, etc. came up and some of them seem to be very old and deprecated. So we are trying to get a clear idea, what are the current technologies and which ones should not be used anymore.

Which editors would be good? Are there any that support the deployment with plugins to use directly from the IDE?

Also if there is a sample project out there that does all that or most, it would be a real help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal "state of the art" is as the following:

- For each (mirco)service I am creating a separate Git repository in
  AWS CodeCommit
- Each repository has its own CI/CD pipeline with AWS CodePipeline. The pipeline has the following stages:

  - Source (AWS CodeCommit)
  - Build (AWS CodeBuild)
  - Deploy Staging[*] (AWS CloudFormation)
  - Approval (Manual Approval)
  - Deploy Production[*] (AWS CloudFormation)

The whole infrastructure and pipeline is written in CloudFormation (in [AWS SAM Syntax](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md)) and I **highly recommend** to do it so as well. This will also help you to tackle your requirement "*[...] completely without the aws web interface.*"

**[*]**: Both stages are using the same(!) AWS CloudFormation template, I just pass a different `Environment` parameter into the infrastructure template to be able to make [some differences](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html) based on the env.

Most of my services are written in TypeScript, to develop it I am using [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) with [a cool plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7371-aws-cloudformation) to help me writing AWS CloudFormation templates.

---

Example of `pipeline.yml`:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  RepositoryName:
    Type: String
  ArtifactStoreBucket:
    Type: String

Resources:
  Pipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      RoleArn: !GetAtt CodePipelineRole.Arn
      ArtifactStore:
        Location: !Ref ArtifactStoreBucket
        Type: S3
      Stages:
        - Name: Source
          Actions:
            - Name: CodeCommit
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Source
                Owner: AWS
                Version: 1
                Provider: CodeCommit
              Configuration:
                RepositoryName: !Ref RepositoryName
                BranchName: master
              InputArtifacts: []
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: SourceOutput
              RunOrder: 1
        - Name: Build
          Actions:
            - Name: Build
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Build
                Owner: AWS
                Version: 1
                Provider: CodeBuild
              Configuration:
                ProjectName: !Ref Build
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: SourceOutput
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: BuildOutput
              RunOrder: 1
        - Name: Staging
          Actions:
            - Name: Deploy
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Deploy
                Owner: AWS
                Version: 1
                Provider: CloudFormation
              Configuration:
                ActionMode: CREATE_UPDATE
                Capabilities: CAPABILITY_IAM,CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND
                StackName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-Infrastructure-Staging
                RoleArn: !GetAtt CloudFormationRole.Arn
                TemplatePath: BuildOutput::infrastructure-packaged.yml
                ParameterOverrides:
                  !Sub |
                  {
                    "Environment": "Staging"
                  }
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: BuildOutput
              OutputArtifacts: []
              RunOrder: 1
        - Name: Approval
          Actions:
            - Name: Approval
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Approval
                Owner: AWS
                Version: 1
                Provider: Manual
              InputArtifacts: []
              OutputArtifacts: []
              RunOrder: 1
        - Name: Production
          Actions:
            - Name: Deploy
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Deploy
                Owner: AWS
                Version: 1
                Provider: CloudFormation
              Configuration:
                ActionMode: CREATE_UPDATE
                Capabilities: CAPABILITY_IAM,CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND
                StackName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-Infrastructure-Production
                RoleArn: !GetAtt CloudFormationRole.Arn
                TemplatePath: BuildOutput::infrastructure-packaged.yml
                ParameterOverrides:
                  !Sub |
                  {
                    "Environment": "Production"
                  }
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: BuildOutput
              OutputArtifacts: []
              RunOrder: 1

  Build:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    Properties:
      Artifacts:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
      Environment:
        ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_MEDIUM
        Image: aws/codebuild/nodejs:10.14.1
        Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-Build
      ServiceRole: !Ref CodeBuildRole
      Source:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
        BuildSpec:
          !Sub |
          version: 0.2
          phases:
            build:
              commands:
                - npm install
                - npm run lint
                - npm run test:unit
                - npm run build
                - aws cloudformation package --s3-bucket ${ArtifactStoreBucket} --template-file ./infrastructure.yml --output-template-file infrastructure-packaged.yml
          artifacts:
            files:
              - infrastructure-packaged.yml

  BuildLogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      RetentionInDays: 14
      LogGroupName: !Sub /aws/codebuild/${Build}

  CodePipelineRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: codepipeline.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: CodePipelineRolePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - iam:PassRole
                Resource:
                  - !GetAtt CloudFormationRole.Arn
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:*
                Resource:
                  - !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${ArtifactStoreBucket}/*
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - codecommit:*
                Resource:
                  - !Sub arn:aws:codecommit:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${RepositoryName}
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - codebuild:*
                Resource:
                  - !Sub arn:aws:codebuild:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:project/${AWS::StackName}-Build
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - cloudformation:*
                Resource:
                  - !Sub arn:aws:cloudformation:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:stack/${AWS::StackName}-Infrastructure-Staging/*
                  - !Sub arn:aws:cloudformation:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:stack/${AWS::StackName}-Infrastructure-Production/*

  CodeBuildRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: codebuild.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: CodeBuildRolePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:*
                Resource:
                  - !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${ArtifactStoreBucket}/*
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - codecommit:*
                Resource:
                  - !Sub arn:aws:codecommit:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${RepositoryName}
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - logs:*
                Resource:
                  - !Sub arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/codebuild/${AWS::StackName}-Build*

  CloudFormationRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: cloudformation.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess
```

Example of `infrastructure.yml`:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Parameters:
  Environment:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - Staging
      - Production

Resources:
  Api:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: api.handler
      CodeUri: .build
      Runtime: nodejs10.x
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 10
      Events:
        ProxyApi:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /{proxy+}
            Method: ANY
      Environment:
        Variables:
          ENVIRONMENT: !Ref Environment
      DeploymentPreference:
        Enabled: false

  ApiLogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      RetentionInDays: 14
      LogGroupName: !Sub /aws/lambda/${Api}

Outputs:
  ApiEndpoint:
    Value: !Sub https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.${AWS::URLSuffix}/${ServerlessRestApiProdStage}
```